# Remove zero before decimal point in php

Tags: php, string

What is the best way to remove zero before decimal point in php?
These are the two I know of:

```
ltrim(0.357, '0'); //.357

preg_replace("/0\./i", ".", 0.357); //.357
```

Are there any better method? Which of them is faster?

Comment: Why you need faster way if you are using predefined functions. They already cause it to utmost fast performance.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it mathematically with floor() function

```
$n = 0.375;
$whole = floor($n);      // 0
$fraction = $n - $whole; // .375
```